# How to add new 3 line in response to a specific 3 line in nginx.conf file using powershell script

Tags: powershell

For example, in the nginx.conf file, delete the following 3 lines and add the value in **$replace**

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                   '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                   '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

$replace=

```
 log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user $time_iso8601 [$request_time] "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
```

This is my script

```
$Nginx_home = "I:\nginx\nginx-1.22.1"
$filePath = "$Nginx_home\conf\nginx.conf"

$now = (Get-Date).tostring("MM-dd-yyyy_HH_mm_ss")

Copy-Item -Path "$filePath" -Destination "$Nginx_home\conf\nginx_$now.conf" -PassThru



$Find = {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
}


$Replace = {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user $time_iso8601 [$request_time] "$request" '
                        '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
}


(Get-Content $Nginx_home\conf\nginx.conf -raw) -replace ([regex]::escape($Find)), $Replace | Set-Content $Nginx_home\conf\nginx1.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx to replace this, you just need to read the file in with `-raw` to get it as a multi-line string so you can replace it all at once.

```
$Find = @'
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                   '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                   '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
'@

$Replace = @'
 log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user $time_iso8601 [$request_time] "$request" '
                     '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                     '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
'@
(Get-Content nginx.conf -raw) -replace ([regex]::escape($Find)), $Replace | Set-Content nginx.updated.conf
```

Comment: After executing this script no changes are made in nginx.conf file

Comment: I did have it create a new nginx.updated.conf file, did you check that one? if you have a snippet of the file that includes what you want to replace I could test better, but that worked for me with what I mocked up based on your question.

Comment: I checked nginx.updated.conf file, Its not change that line.

Comment: like I said, it worked on my end with what I made up to test with. If you can provide a better example to test against I might be able to figure out why it's not working on your end.

Comment: Iam unable to send my script in comment box

Comment: You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75250639/edit) your question to update it for something like that.